# MSYS2 why doesn't adding "mingw" to fstab have any effect?

Tags: fstab, mingw, msys

The package I'm working on uses Autotools -- autoconf, libtools, configure, etc.  I'm developing with MinGW-W64 on Windows XP sp3.

In it's infinite wisdom, libtools has decided that my system files (NATIVE_SYSTEM_HEADER_DIR) are in **/mingw/include**.  This directory does not exist in the MinGW-W64 constellation.  There are mingw32 and mingw64, of course...  And I can see using mingw as an alias to be pointed where needed.

So I edited **C:\msys32\etc\fstab** to add an entry `C:\msys32\mingw32\     /mingw` figuring that was the quickest way past the problem, and an easy thing to change if I start compiling 64 bit versions.

**This had no effect.**  It is as if the MSYS2 startup ignores a `mingw` entry as a special case under "things that may be a potential problem" (like the cygwin directories).

Can anyone explain what's happening?  Is the a "correct" way to bring `mingw/include` into existence so libtools will get what it needs?

---

BTW, being too new to add tags, I observe that the tags available to me are incorrect/ambiguous.  MSYS2 is different than it's historical predecessor MSYS.  Likewise, mingw is not mingw-w64.  I regret any misleading tags.